# basic idea of a custom tooltip, using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I need basic idea of creating a custom tooltip using pure `Javascript` code;

*What I want :*

**For example :**

```
<a href="#" onmousemover="tooltip('text')">Link Text</a>
```

And `onmouseover` I want to display a custom tooltip with `fixed position` based on `<a>`'s element `position`, to start from `right:0` or from `left:0` of the `<a>` element;

Comment: Why so many `what have you tried` these days, where would these people go for help who are beginners ? Hate those words !

Comment: @DavidThomas the only problem I had, was with position of created tooltip, I thought I did it right, but the position was not as I expected it to be

Comment: @Sarfraz: I have no objection to helping someone who's tried nothing, but, if something's been attempted, I'd rather start with that foreknowledge. While I accept that the opening question may appear to be somewhat over-aggressive, the more-important parts are the subsequent questions, though they build off the foundations of the first.

Comment: @DavidThomas: That makes sense then and I totally agree with you in that sense :)

Comment: I don't know whether you're still around or whether you have found something suited in the meantime, but I created just that last week. It is posted as answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458970/popup-tooltip-position-in-jquerymobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this question comes up when a user searches for `custom tooltip`, I would like to add the bootstrap's JS tooltip, although you have mentioned *pure javascript*. So in a sense this answer is only to give the future readers another nice option to work with.

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp) for how to use bootstrap tooltip plugin. And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp) to learn about the options and methods available at your disposal when using Bootstrap's JS Tooltip.

Still I am giving the `tryit` from their site here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip */

.test+.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Tooltip on top */

.test+.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
}


/* Tooltip on bottom */

.test+.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}


/* Tooltip on left */

.test+.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}


/* Tooltip on right */

.test+.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Tooltip CSS Example</h3>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a></li>
      <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Bottom</a></li>
      <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
      <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Despite your intention, it still doesn't answer the question and doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Rob On one hand you are right, it doesn't belong here. But on the other hand, considering the P.S. in the answer, I think it *sort of* does belong here. Note the *sort of*, again. :-)

Answer (score 8):

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" tooltip="Go to Google">Google</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    tip, text,
    base = document.createElement('tooltip'); //Defining all objects

for (var x=0;x < a.length;x++) { //I'm using "for" loop to get all "a" elements with attribute "tooltip".
     a[x].onmouseover = function () {
         text = this.getAttribute('tooltip');
         tip = document.createTextNode(text);
         if (text != null) {// Checking if tooltip is empty or not.
               base.innerHTML = '';
               base.appendChild(tip);
               if (document.getElementsByTagName('tooltip')[0]){// Checking for any "tooltip" element
                   document.getElementsByTagName('tooltip')[0].remove();// Removing old tooltip
               }
               base.style.top = (event.pageY + 20) + 'px';
               base.style.left = (event.pageX + 20) + 'px';
               document.body.appendChild(base);
         }

     };
     a[x].onmouseout = function () {
         document.getElementsByTagName('tooltip')[0].remove();// Remove last tooltip
     };
}

})();
```

By including this script into your page, you just have to use `tooltip="Text"` in any HTML Element

**CSS**

```
tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

You can edit CSS as your wish!

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naman00/uc4mjbze/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a function something like this:

```
function tooltip(text, element) {

    var offsetDistance = 20;

    tt = document.getElementById('ttdiv');
    elem = document.getElementById(element.id);
    tt.style.top = elem.offsetTop + offsetDistance + 'px';
    tt.style.left = elem.offsetLeft + offsetDistance + 'px';
    tt.style.display = 'block';
    tt.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Where `ttdiv` is the id of the tooltip div, that is initially set to `display:none`. You'll need an accompanying `hide()` function to hide the tooltip when `onmouseout` is triggered.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/vKw9S/1/).