# Show info when hovering over a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm implementing a function such that when you hover a link it will show a **tooltip**.

Here is an example:

[image]

Is there any other javascript library that implements this functionality?(preferably the same one as the image)

Comment: You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971637/basic-idea-of-a-custom-tooltip-using-pure-javascript) Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) you have [Popover.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) available

```
    //JS
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })

    //HTML
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
        Click to toggle popover
    </button>
```

You can change the `trigger` value for the Popover to be a `hover` also.

Second option for Bootstrap is [Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) although it does not look like your example.

---

Also jQuery UI has it's own version of [Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: awesome. I think this is what im looking for... ill try this tomorrow.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also recommend you to see on [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) - Pure css hint library

Answer (score 1):

This might help.
You can do it with help of css or title in any tag in HTML.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-tooltips-courtesy-of-html5-data-attributes--webdesign-4826